# Sorting an array in reverse order

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm going over the logic behind the combined comparison operator and it's ability to reverse the sort order of an array. For example, I could reverse the order of the following array:

```
books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", 
"A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]
```

by adding this line of code:

```
books.sort! { |firstBook, secondBook| secondBook <=> firstBook }
```

My question is, why would I not be able to just call:

```
books.reverse!
```

on this array to get the reverse order?

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: "why would I not be able to just call" You *are* able to do that. What is your question?

Comment: I think I was just more confused as to why .reverse wouldn't sort the array in reverse order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reverse` just reverses the order of the array, and does not sort it:

```
irb> arr = [3,1,5]
=> [3, 1, 5]

irb> arr.sort
=> [1, 3, 5]
irb> arr.sort {|x,y| y<=>x}
=> [5, 3, 1]
irb> arr.reverse
=> [5, 1, 3]
```

But of course you can combine `sort` and `reverse` to sort in reverse order:

```
irb> arr.sort.reverse
=> [5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I find it weird that `sort` doesn't have an argument that does that